# Monotouch and uialertview do not show special characters (æ,ø,å) correct

Tags: character-encoding, xamarin.ios, uialertview

Hey Guys If I do this in mono touch:

```
        var alert = new UIAlertView { Message = "Prøv igen" };

            alert.AddButton("Nej");
            alert.AddButton("Ja");

            alert.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ButtonIndex == 0)
                {
                    //do nothing - go away
                }
                if (e.ButtonIndex == 1)
                {

                }
            };

            alert.Show();
```

The  Uialert dot not show "Prøv igen" correct but like this "Pr[]v igen". You got any ideas to  solve this - should I create a string with specific encoding?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of the source file was saved with Western european. I changed the encoding in advanced save options i visual studio to utf8 and the issue disappeared.